# Consume unsafe self signed certificate endpoint

Tags: angular, typescript, ssl, ionic2

I'm trying to get an `oauth_token` from my drupal webserver.

Now when I try to connect to the `url` which provides this oauth token, my app doesn't do anything.

Before I execute the http request I show the url to be called in an alert. After I entered this url in postman, I got a 'Cannot contact server'. So I changed in my settings that it should trust unsafe SSL certificates.

When I execute the url again, I do get the correct response. Note, this is the exact same url the app is calling.

So now I have the following (sample) code:

```
try{
   this.http.get('serverUrl/oauth/request_token?'+ correct_oauth_variables)
      .subscribe(data => {
         alert("YAY! Data: " + data);
      }, err => {
         alert("Nope... " + err);
      });
} catch(ex) {
   alert("Request failed because: " + ex);
}
```

But it keeps loading forever. Not a single alert is executed. I suppose this is the same issue that postman was having, not being able to connect at all. So is it in someway possible to allow/trust unsafe SSL certificates? It'js just for development purposes.

---

### tl;dr / Recap

Angular2/Ionic can't reach the unsafe server. When I allow unsafe ssl in postman and execute the exact same url, it does work. WIthout, it doesn't. How can I allow unsafe ssl certificates in Angular 2?

Comment: First, you don't need this try/catch. After removing this, if you inspect the network tab in the browser, is the request being sent to the server?

Comment: I placed the try-catch there just to check if it would throw an unexpected error and maybe show that alert, which it doesnt. I can't inspect the call in the browser since for this part you'll need cordova to run. Note that it did run earlier with a different server, only the ip and ssl certificate changed.

Comment: I really don't understand why u can't inspect the network tab from your browser. If ou are testing your app within the browser (ionic serve), you just need to open its debug. If you are testing with a real device, just need to open the debug, too, and inspect the connected devices. I think this (check whether the request is being made or not) is your best shot to solve this.